# Convert forecast time produced by arima into standard date time

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, arima

I have performed forecasting using ARIMA :

Forecasts results look like below:

```
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
15552001       18.80470 18.52527 19.08413 18.37735 19.23206
15555601       18.94718 18.63358 19.26078 18.46758 19.42679
15559201       18.86774 18.53623 19.19924 18.36074 19.37473
15562801       18.84979 18.46603 19.23355 18.26288 19.43670
15566401       18.91506 18.52182 19.30830 18.31366 19.51646
15570001       18.86569 18.46538 19.26599 18.25347 19.47791
15573601       18.86727 18.45311 19.28143 18.23387 19.50067
15577201       18.89555 18.47853 19.31258 18.25777 19.53334
15580801       18.86784 18.44715 19.28854 18.22444 19.51125
15584401       18.87419 18.44782 19.30056 18.22212 19.52627
15588001       18.88546 18.45692 19.31399 18.23007 19.54085
15591601       18.87097 18.43914 19.30280 18.21054 19.53139
15595201       18.87679 18.44097 19.31262 18.21025 19.54334
15598801       18.88064 18.44225 19.31904 18.21018 19.55111
15602401       18.87349 18.43165 19.31533 18.19775 19.54923
15606001       18.87755 18.43210 19.32300 18.19630 19.55880
15609601       18.87844 18.43003 19.32685 18.19265 19.56423
15613201       18.87510 18.42320 19.32701 18.18397 19.56623
15616801       18.87759 18.42224 19.33293 18.18120 19.57397
15620401       18.87748 18.41899 19.33597 18.17627 19.57868
15624001       18.87602 18.41411 19.33793 18.16959 19.58245
15627601       18.87742 18.41219 19.34264 18.16592 19.58891
```

I want to convert this point into human readable date time. How do I do that?

My initial dataframe has epoch times as row.names like :

```
         y
```

1484337600  19.22819
1484341200  19.28906
1484344800  19.28228
1484348400  19.21669
1484352000  19.32759
1484355600  19.21833
1484359200  19.20626
1484362800  19.28737
1484366400  19.20651
1484370000  19.18424

This initial dataset I converted using :

```
xts_dataframe <- xts(x = dataframe$y, order.by = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(row.names(dataframe)), origin="1970-01-01"))



fit <- auto.arima(ts_dataframe ,trace = TRUE,stepwise = FALSE)  #411 
  fc <- forecast(fit,h=24)
  fc <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(fc$mean), origin = '1970-01-01')
  print(fc)
```

It's giving output like this now:

```
[1] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
  [3] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
  [5] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
  [7] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
  [9] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [11] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [13] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [15] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [17] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [19] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [21] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
 [23] "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST" "1969-12-31 16:00:18 PST"
```

with no prediction results.

Problem -2 : If I do not make any changes to point in my forecast result :

```
 fit <- auto.arima(ts_dataframe ,trace = TRUE,stepwise = FALSE)
    fc <- forecast(fit,h=24)
    print(fc)
```

I get result which I have posted at top. In this epoch time are of 1970 but it should be something after the last epoch time in my original dataframe. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check out the new `sweep` package. Here's a [recent post](http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2017/07/09/sweep-0-1-0.html) describing the process. The following inputs based on your data frame:

- `data` is your data frame with a **column of dates or datetimes** and a column of values
- `freq` is your frequency and `start` is your start for the `ts` object
- `h` is your forecast periods into the future

Here's the general process.

```
library(forecast)
library(sweep)
library(timekit)

# Make ts with tk_ts()
data_ts <- tk_ts(data, freq = freq, start = start)

# auto.arima()
fit <- auto.arima(data_ts)

# Make forecast
fcast <- forecast(fit, h = h)

# Use sw_sweep with timekit_idx = TRUE
sw_sweep(fcast, timekit_idx = T)
```

Comment: Thankd fro your response. Can you tell me how do I apply frequency of 1 hour or 5 mins in data_ts <- tk_ts(data, freq = freq, start = start) ?

Comment: Can you please tell is it possible to apply hourly frequency in this tk_ts() method?

Comment: The `ts` system uses regularized time series specified with a frequency and a start. The start doesn't matter as much except for pretty printing, but the frequency is important. I'd take a look at your data and try to figure out you base period. For monthly data, you'd set `freq = 12` because it repeats every year. If data is collected in 1 hour frequency, I'd set `freq = 24` and `start = 1`. If 5 minute intervals, I'd set `freq = 60 / 5` since there are 12 observations each hour.

Comment: I figured out there are other variants for of tk_methods which can be used for frequency like hourly minute. I'm using something like this: tk_xts_dataframe <- tk_xts(dataframe, start = start_time , end = end_time,  freq = 24) but here I'm specifying start and end time as that of my dataframe . Is this correct?

Comment: But one thing what I want to ask is even if I'm using final <- sw_sweep(fc , timekit_idx = TRUE) ; in my output I'm getting time in my final result as : 3600, 7200 etc. why it's not showing time according to my initial dataframe. What difference sweep does in my case? I'm still not seeing times according to my intial data frame.

Comment: You might want to email me a reproducible example: info@business-science.io. Send me your data and code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Mailed. Please check

Answer (score 1):

i hope this is how your data looks like

```
> head(data)
       epoch        y
1 1484341200 19.28906
2 1484344800 19.28228
3 1484348400 19.21669
4 1484352000 19.32759
5 1484355600 19.21833
6 1484359200 19.20626

> data$epoch <- as.POSIXct(data$epoch, origin = '1970-01-01')

> head(data)
                epoch        y
1 2017-01-14 02:30:00 19.28906
2 2017-01-14 03:30:00 19.28228
3 2017-01-14 04:30:00 19.21669
4 2017-01-14 05:30:00 19.32759
5 2017-01-14 06:30:00 19.21833
6 2017-01-14 07:30:00 19.20626

> xts_dataframe <- xts(data$y, order.by = data$epoch)
> fit <- auto.arima(xts_dataframe ,trace = TRUE,stepwise = FALSE)
> fc <- forecast(fit,h=24)

> fc <- as.data.frame(fc)
> time1 <- as.data.frame(seq(tail(data$epoch,1)+60, length.out = nrow(fc), by = "30 min"))

> output <- as.data.frame(cbind(time1[,1],fc))
> print(output)
```

Comment: fit <- auto.arima(ts_dataframe ,trace = TRUE,stepwise = FALSE) 
fc <- forecast(fit,h=10)
print(fc) okay so, where do i put your line of code to view the entire forecast like above but time should be proper datetime.

Comment: `output <-  as.POSIXct( fc$mean, origin = '1970-01-01')` . This will give the point forecast value in datetime format. If you want the Lo80, Lo95, Hi80, HI95 to be in datetime format, replace the fc$mean by fc$lower[,1] and so on..

Comment: So, I have tried your code using:  fc <- forecast(fit,h=forecast_duration)
  fc.dates <- as.POSIXct(fc$mean, origin = '1970-01-01'). It throws error:Error in as.POSIXct.default(fc$mean, origin = "1970-01-01") : 
  do not know how to convert 'fc$mean' to class “POSIXct”
Calls: process_data_for_forecast -> forecast_data -> as.POSIXct -> as.POSIXct.default
Execution halted

Comment: origin is in single quote only.

Comment: the  forecast data which i got is already posted. Are you asking for intial dataset on which I'm applying ARIMA?

Comment: Yes, thats the one. You need to check your structure.

Comment: actually I'm fine with the epoch times in my forecast result. But it's 1970's epoch time. I couldn;t understand why its not starting from the last epoch time in my original dataset

Comment: oh so you have created separate column of epoch time. In my initial dataframe epoch's are present in row. names.

Comment: 1) I am converting fc to data frame class. 2) i am taking the time sequential of epoch .,i.e. I am taking the last time of epoch in data and counting till no.of. predicted results [which is 24 here]. 3) I am binding the column of time and fc as you have asked for human readable datetime

Comment: What is by 30 min  and +60 here in 2nd line?

Comment: Your initial data in epoch has 30 min interval for every observation. so the prediction must have the same time interval.

Comment: I have just given an example to study here. you need to do on your own according to your requirements. i gave 30,  becoz in my example i showed 30 mins interval.  if you want 60, give 60. if its 30 sec, give 30 sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are awesome!

Comment: Last timestamp in my initial dataset is : 2017-07-12 23:00:00 , and forecast result has 1st value as : 15552001 2017-07-12 23:01:00  instead it should be 2017-07-13 00:00:00 right? how come it is : 2017-07-12 23:01:00?

Comment: you must have given it as 1 min. give it as 1 hour or 60 min instead of 1 min.

Comment: I have done like this :  time1 <- as.data.frame(seq(tail(dataframe$timestamp,1)+60, length.out = nrow(fc), by = "60 min"))
  output <- as.data.frame(cbind(time1[,1],fc))

Comment: is it considering that 60 as 60 seconds?

Comment: yes. you r right . the +60 here is 1 min. so, for 1 hour its +(60*60) .   `time1 <- as.data.frame(seq(tail(dataframe$timestamp,1)+ (60*60), length.out = nrow(fc), by = "60 min"))`

Comment: don't you think, this way we have just put a hack and added a column to the dataframe which gives timestamps we want but not produced by arima result. Arima result is giving epoch time which is correct, what it did it it started from Jan 1970 so histirical data ended at june, epoch time which we got is also correct it started right after where historical ends, Problem is its considering 1970's not our timestamps

Comment: any reason why?

Comment: If you want timestamps to be predicted, you need to add that as well to arima. which becomes multi variate time series data. What you are doing above is univariate, in such cases, arima cannot give the value of timestamps on its own. In other words, you are just predicting a single variable 'y'. maybe you should check with other functions or packages that gives both prediction and timestamps

Comment: then how come it produced epoch times in result as i described in my last comment. But it considered historical data to be something in 1970's and produced epoch times in my forecast right after historical epoch ended.

Comment: Thats because it did not consider the timestamp in your initial data during arima process. and Thats how arima works. It will give datetime values  of prediction from 1970's only.

Comment: I remember you said " It will give datetime values of prediction from 1970's only", when i thought about it, I realised that why epoch time its showig in output why not normal time. If it can give epoch time as output, can't we give epoch time as start and end interval while creating timeseries object instead of xts object and frequency of 3600(for 1 hour)? What do you think?